# How to access the item in an object of an array by index number?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I wish to access the object '2016-11-12' inside the $scope.list and display the Order and Balance. How could achieve that?

List:

```
$scope.list = {
  ItemCode:'item1',
  '2016-11-12':[{Order:'1',Balanace:'2'}],
  '2016-11-15':[{Order:' ',Balanace:' '}]
}
```

I've tried `indexof` but it seems doesn't work.

```
$scope.list[0].indexof(1)
```

Any idea and suggestion will be great!

Comment: `$scope.list['2016-11-12' ]`

Comment: is there a way to access by index number instead of the text?

Comment: like `$scope.list[1]` then i will get my '2016-11-12' index

Comment: @VincentTang `Object.keys($scope.list)[0]` ... but order may vary

Comment: Alright,  this is what I want!!!  THX!!!

Answer (score 0):

To access Order value for a given date:

`$scope.list['2016-11-12'][0]['Order']`

To access Balance value for a given date (you misspelled balance btw):

`$scope.list['2016-11-12'][0]['Balance']`

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets notation:

```
$scope.list['2016-11-12'];
```

**See Example:**

```js
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);

app.controller("testCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.list = {
  ItemCode:'item1',
  '2016-11-12':[{Order:'1',Balanace:'2'}],
  '2016-11-15':[{Order:' ',Balanace:' '}]
};
  
  $scope.test = $scope.list['2016-11-12'];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="TestApp">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    {{test}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should not answer questions that are this basic. You should search for necessary post and mark it as duplicate

Comment: I tend to agree with you on that one I must say... I had my doubts while posting this answer..

Answer (score 0):

What you have called $scope.list is actually an object instead of an array as you seem to expect. The '2016-11-12' is a field in that object that has an array value, inside which there is only one object. A more flexible way to construct your object would be to put the objects in an array inside the item object and then access them by index.

```
$scope.list = {
ItemCode:'item1',
ThingsArray:[
 {Date:'2016-11-12', Order:'1',Balanace:'2'},
 {Date:'2016-11-15', Order:' ',Balanace:' '}
 ]
}
```

Then you can access them using `$scope.list.ThingsArray[0]` Note that I have moved the dates into the objects themselves.